# How to implement the dislike-like button

Tags: html

I am developing a web page with rating mechanism, so I need two buttons called "dislike" and "like", once clicked, the rating information would be sent to the server to update the related rating information. What html code should I use, could you give a little code for doing this?

Comment: Coding related questions belong on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using? Also, you will most likely need JavaScript for this if you want the rating system to be like SO, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML itself cannot achieve this.  You need server-side functionality to recognize that a vote has been made and save that vote.  This will require some form of data store (most likely a database).  Does your site currently use a database?

If you provide some more specific information about your site, we can help further.

Answer (score 1):

**I am leaving this answer in case if someone else faces this problem in future :**

As said by Kaleb , this functionality can not be achieved by html itself, **database is must for this** because once you close the html page your upvote and downvote counter will be gone.

What you need to do is :

1. In your database , make a table say **"votes"** .
2. This table should have following columns

   - voteup  - this should be filled with two options either **yes** or **no**
   - votedown - this should also be filled with two values "**yes**" or "**no**"
   - voteup_count -This will count the total of upvotes
   - vote_down - This will count the total of downvotes

   **Working**

   - Before rendering your html page , check the corresponding entries into database whether the particular post is already upvoted  or downvoted
   - If the post is **upvoted** and you again click the **upvoted** button the button text should change from **upvoted** to **upvote** and the counter should be decremented by 1 in the database as well under the **voteup_count** column
   - If the post is neither **upvoted** nor **downvoted** whenever the button is clicked it should increment the respective counter and then again change the button text either to **upvoted** or **downvoted**
   - ***of course your like and dislike button should also be dynamically created for each form.***